# What chemistry other than that on Earth could support life on an alien planet?

Tags: evolution, xenobiology, aliens, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

I like designing aliens, similar to how Biblaridion did it on his videos on YT where he establishes the world conditions and chemistry of the world and proceed to create an evolutionary tree from simple plankton like life to land dwelling ecosystems.

My issue is that I do not really have any chemistry knowledge, and I do not know what could I tweak to make it more interesting. I do plan to stick to carbon as the building block for life but it is in my understanding that something other than water could be the main solvent on the planet and that some of this substances can even facilitate life in extreme conditions.

What do you think?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello Radu. I apologize for voting to close your question, but we need to close it to give us time to help you refine your question. Per our [help/on-topic], we're here to help you overcome specific problems, not fill in the gaps of missing years of education. Many questions have been asked on this Stack about other solvents than water, so I recommend starting with a search of our Stack. When you do ask your questions, you need to be very specific (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... for example, what do you mean by "extreme conditions?" You'll discover that specifically defining that takes some thought. The snow of Alaska, the heat of Death Valley, the atmosphere of Venus... those are all "extreme conditions" depending on the context of the question. You might consider using our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/40609) to help you craft your question.

Comment: check it out:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=solvents

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you face is the enormity of chemistry and chemical possibilities. With just a few dozen atoms it is very easy to come up with a formula for a new molecule that nobody has (in all likelihood) ever synthesized, but (in all likelihood) could be synthesized. With molecules containing thousands, millions or even billions of atoms the scope is so vast that you might as well accept humanity is entirely ignorant of all possible compounds to a good approximation.

Coupled with this enormity of possibilities is the chemical complexity and variety of life’s biochemistry in the one example we have to study. For those who are not familiar with the extent or complexity of life have a look here and use the arrows bottom right to scroll: http://biochemical-pathways.com/#/map/1

So it’s a somewhat daunting task to try to invent a new alien biochemistry from scratch. The further you deviate from what we know the harder it will become and the less reference points there will be. As an example even within the tiny scope of what humanity knows the possibilities are endless. Thousands of amino acids have been discovered or synthesized in multiple forms of “handedness” any of which might under some specific circumstance form part of an alien biochemistry. And there are also a multiplicity of purine and pyrimidine bases as well as sugars, all of which might form some alien RNA or DNA. That is assuming that something vaguely chemically similar to RNA or DNA is used. Perhaps it uses something else entirely from the depths of the chemical unknown.